# How to get a substring between two substrings in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, substring

I Have a column in Dataframe in which the data is as below.

| Invoice Number |
| --- |
| Being InvoiceNC/0095/2022.23 Dt. 06.10.2022 |
| Black Toner Cartridge agst InvoiceNC/0098/2022.23 dt 10.10.2022 |
| Being amount vide InvoiceS0001236 Dt. 03.10.2022 |
| Being amount vide InvoiceS0001235 Dt. 03.10.2022 |

I'd like to remove everything from the column but the string between 'Invoice' and next " ".

Any help will be appretiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = df['Invoice Number'].str.extract('Invoice(\S+)')
```

`s`

```
    0
0   NC/0095/2022.23
1   NC/0098/2022.23
2   S0001236
3   S0001235
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

```
df['Invoice Number']=a
l=[]
k=[]
for i in range(len(a)):
    l.append(a[i].split('Invoice')[1])
    k.append(l[i].split(' ')[0])

df['Invoice Number']=k# replace  in df by new values
```